# Creating a Single DLL for Silverlight and Non-Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization, cross-platform

All of my cross-platform libraries are created with solutions that have two projects: one that builds on the Silverlight CLR and one on the regular CLR. Hence, every library I make has two DLLs: name.dll and nameSilverlight.dll.

This is, as far as I know today, the only way to do it.

However, I recently tried Mike Talbot's "Silverlight Serializer" DLL, and **I could include the same DLL in a C# desktop and in a Silverlight application.** It's the exact same file.

How did he do that? And how can I do that?

(I really need to do it, because I'm trying to serialize in a desktop app and deserialize in a Silverlight app, and the assemblies are not matching up because they're different.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight 3 is a "lowest common denominator" and if you just use base/core classes, you can compile a DLL there and reference it directly from .NET. You cannot, without the portable library, do the converse however.

Comment: It seems from Mike's blog that this won't work if you use LINQ in your code. That's a huge negative. I guess I'll have to try both approaches and see what works with the serialization.

Comment: +1 I managed to make the DLL, but it looks like it has an issue with persistence.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that they are using the [Portable Library CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/01/19/announcing-portable-library-tools-ctp-justin-van-patten.aspx).

Comment: How do I then convert an existing project to CTP? This seems like a beta tool.

Comment: @ashes999: Install the ctp, and change the project type.

Comment: Maybe not. I'm using VS Express :(

Comment: @ashes999: Did you install sp1?

Comment: @Reed I thought SP1 is only for non-Express versoins of VS.

Comment: @ashes999: Nope - from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5   "This installer is for all editions of Visual Studio 2010 (Express, Professional, Premium, Ultimate, Test Professional)"

Comment: I'm getting some error about silverlight_sdk.msi missing. I don't want more libraries; let me look at it again later.